# function is not working properly

Tags: javascript, dom, canvas

I have a problem with my functions for when a enemy shoots a laser. I have done so much debugging on this, i just cannot figure out why it is not working.

When i have my code like this it will shoot to the top of my playArea but not to the bottom (boundary is spelt wrong because i done it from the beginning)

```
for (var i = 0; i < enemylasers.length; i++){
        if(parseInt(enemylasers[i][0].style.top) > playArea.topBoundry){
            enemylasers[i][1] -= laserSpeed;
            enemylasers[i][0].style.top = enemylasers[i][1] + 'px';
        }else{
            playArea.removeChild(enemylasers[i][0]);
            enemylasers.splice(i,1);
        }
    }
```

When i change some of the code around to what i think might be right, it isnt and just does not make the lasers shoot anywhere. here is what i changed it to.

```
for (var i = 0; i < enemylasers.length; i++){
        if(parseInt(enemylasers[i][0].style.top) > playArea.bottomBoundry){
            enemylasers[i][1] += laserSpeed;
            enemylasers[i][0].style.top = enemylasers[i][1] + 'px';
        }else{
            playArea.removeChild(enemylasers[i][0]);
            enemylasers.splice(i,1);
        }
    }
```

This is what creates my enemies laser

```
function createenemylaser(){
    if(enemylasers.length < enemymaxlasers){ 
            var laserpush = Math.floor(Math.random()*enemies.length);
            var laser = enemylaser();
            laser.classList.add('enemylaser');
            laser.style.top = enemies[laserpush][1] + 'px';
            laser.style.left = parseInt(enemies[laserpush][0].offsetLeft) +'px';
            playArea.appendChild(laser);
            enemylasers.push([laser, enemies[laserpush][1]]);
    }
}
    setInterval(createenemylaser, 2000);
```

And this is my enemies lasers array

```
enemylasers=[],
    enemylaserspeed = 5,
    enemymaxlasers= 8,
```

And this is what creates the div for my enemy laser

```
function enemylaser(){
    return document.createElement('div');
}
```

I hope someone can help, i am not that experienced in javascript but i know quiet abit.

Comment: Just a note, misspellings like boundary can be fixed in any advanced text editor using Find and Replace All

Comment: okay thankyou i shall do that now

Comment: Be careful to ensure your code doesn't get jacked up in the process

Comment: I have just done it and it changed them all with no console errors, The lasers are not working though. Thanks for that tip though i should have realized that my self lol.

Comment: what happens if you change `parseInt(enemylasers[i][0].style.top) > playArea.bottomBoundry` to `parseInt(enemylasers[i][0].style.top) < playArea.bottomBoundry`

Comment: It works thankyou very much kells! i appreciate it alot!.

Comment: @Kells1986 just for the sake of fairness and completeness, i would suggest that you post the solution in your comment as an answer, and hopefully Tyler will accept that answer (as it obviously helped him) :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since @Chips_100 suggested I should post my solution from the comments section here, here it is:

You needed to change `parseInt(enemylasers[i][0].style.top) > playArea.bottomBoundry` to `parseInt(enemylasers[i][0].style.top) < playArea.bottomBoundry` as you have reversed the direction your lasers are travelling in.